# What were quarterly values of the MSCI "WMA Private Investor Income Index" (TR) for the last 5-6 years?

Tags: united-kingdom, historical-data, market-indexes, financial-advisor, historical-analysis

In the UK, the [WMA indices](https://www.msci.com/wma) are quite popular with "wealth management" types for benchmarking performance of clients' multi-asset portfolios.

I'm interested in finding the historic values of the WMA Private Investor Income Index (total return) for the last 5-6 years with quarterly (or, better, monthly) frequency.

Annual year-on-year changes are included in the [factsheet](https://www.msci.com/documents/1296102/8561339/WMA+PRIVATE+INVESTOR+INCOME.pdf):

[image: WMA performance]

But I can't find anything with higher frequency than that.

MSCI do have a web page [here](https://www.msci.com/end-of-day-data-regional) which can be used to query end-of-day index values on specific days but while it has a pull-down for "Index suite" which includes a "WMA Private Investor Indices" option, it doesn't actually seem to include them.  However the page does say it only serves up "any global, regional or country MSCI index" and it's possible the WMA indices are considered to be a different category to those.